# Trouble to vectorize function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

For a project, I need to generate sample from function. I would like to be able to generate those samples as quickly as possible.

I have this example (in the final version, the `function` lambda will be provided in the arguments) The goal is to generate `ys` of the n points linespaced `xs` between `start` and `stop` using the lambda `function`.

```py
def get_ys(coefficients, num_outputs=20, start=0., stop=1.):
    function = lambda x, args: args[0]*(x-args[1])**2 + args[2]*(x-args[3]) + args[4]
    xs = np.linspace(start, stop, num=num_outputs, endpoint=True)
    ys = [function(x, coefficients) for x in xs]
    return ys
```

```py
%%time
n = 1000
xs = np.random.random((n,5))
ys = np.apply_along_axis(get_ys, 1, xs)

Wall time: 616 ms
```

I am trying to vectorize it, and found `numpy.apply_along_axis`

```py
%%time
for i in range(1000):
    xs = np.random.random(5)
    ys = get_ys(xs)

Wall time: 622 ms
```

Unfortunately it is still pretty slow :/

I am not so familiar with function vectorization, can someone guide me a little bit on how to improve the speed of the script ?

Thanks!

Edit:
example of input/output:

```
xs = np.ones(5)
ys = get_ys(xs)

[1.0, 0.9501385041551247, 0.9058171745152355, 0.8670360110803323, 0.8337950138504155,0.8060941828254848, 0.7839335180055402, 0.7673130193905817, 0.7562326869806094, 0.7506925207756232, 0.7506925207756232, 0.7562326869806094, 0.7673130193905817, 0.7839335180055401, 0.8060941828254847, 0.8337950138504155,  0.8670360110803323, 0.9058171745152354, 0.9501385041551246, 1.0]
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is a convenient way of applying a function that only takes 1d array to a 3d (or larger) array.  For 2d it's simpler to just iterate on one dimension.  In any case it is not a speed tool, and thus is not what we usually mean by "vectorizing".  "vectorizing" usually means rewriting your function so it works with a 2d array, making use of `numpy` methods that work with multidimensional arrays.  There isn't a short cut.  You have to learn `numpy` basics.

Comment: Another way to put it - `apply` is still calling `get_ys` 1000 times.  It doesn't compile it or otherwise make it faster.

Comment: @Gulzar, it is runnable with the code given.  e.g. `get_ys(np.arange(5))` returns a list of 20 values.  This isn't a debugging question, but rather a rewriting one.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh, I didn't know that, I assumed that it would vectorize, my bad. I tried to use the `numpy.vectorize` on the function, but it inserted one element at the time instead of a row, so I thought I needed to use this function..

Comment: `np.vectorize` passes scalar values, not rows.  And it has a performance disclaimer.  `apply....` should have one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_ys(coefficients, num_outputs=20, start=0., stop=1.):
    function = lambda x, args: args[0]*(x-args[1])**2 + args[2]*(x-args[3]) + args[4]
    xs = np.linspace(start, stop, num=num_outputs, endpoint=True)
    ys = [function(x, coefficients) for x in xs]
    return ys
```

You are trying to get around calling `get_ys` 1000 times, once for each row of `xs`.

What will it take to pass `xs` as a whole to `get_ys`?  In other words, what if `coefficients` was (n,5) instead of (5,)?

`xs` is (20,), and the `ys` will be same (right)?

The lambda is write to expect a scalar `x` and (5,) args.  Can it be changed to work with a (20,) `x` and (n,5) `args`?

As a first step, what does `function` produce if given `xs`?  That is instead of

```
ys = [function(x, coefficients) for x in xs]

ys = function(xs, coefficients)
```

As written your code iterates (at slow Python speeds) of the `n` (1000) rows, and the 20 `linspace`.  So `function` is called 20,000 times.  That's what makes your code slow.

### Lets try that change

A sample run with your function:

```
In [126]: np.array(get_ys(np.arange(5)))
Out[126]: 
array([-2.        , -1.89473684, -1.78947368, -1.68421053, -1.57894737,
       -1.47368421, -1.36842105, -1.26315789, -1.15789474, -1.05263158,
       -0.94736842, -0.84210526, -0.73684211, -0.63157895, -0.52631579,
       -0.42105263, -0.31578947, -0.21052632, -0.10526316,  0.        ])
```

Replace the list comprehension with just one call to `function`:

```
In [127]: def get_ys1(coefficients, num_outputs=20, start=0., stop=1.):
     ...:     function = lambda x, args: args[0]*(x-args[1])**2 + args[2]*(x-args[3]) + args[4]
     ...: 
     ...:     xs = np.linspace(start, stop, num=num_outputs, endpoint=True)
     ...:     ys = function(xs, coefficients)
     ...:     return ys
     ...: 
     ...:
```

Same values:

```
In [128]: get_ys1(np.arange(5))
Out[128]: 
array([-2.        , -1.89473684, -1.78947368, -1.68421053, -1.57894737,
       -1.47368421, -1.36842105, -1.26315789, -1.15789474, -1.05263158,
       -0.94736842, -0.84210526, -0.73684211, -0.63157895, -0.52631579,
       -0.42105263, -0.31578947, -0.21052632, -0.10526316,  0.        ])
```

Comparative timings:

```
In [129]: timeit np.array(get_ys(np.arange(5)))
345 µs ± 16.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [130]: timeit get_ys1(np.arange(5))
89.2 µs ± 162 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

That's what we mean by "vectorization" - replacing python level iterations (a list comprehension) with an equivalent that makes fuller user of `numpy` array methods.

I suspect we can move on to work with a (n,5) `coefficients`, but this should be enough to get you started.

### fully vectorized

By `broadcasting` the (n,5) against (20,) I can get a function that does not have any python loops:

```
def get_ys2(coefficients, num_outputs=20, start=0., stop=1.):
    function = lambda x, args: args[:,0]*(x-args[:,1])**2 + args[:,2]*(x-args[:,3]) + args[:,4]
    xs = np.linspace(start, stop, num=num_outputs, endpoint=True)
    ys = function(xs[:,None], coefficients)
    return ys.T
```

And with a (1,5) input:

```
In [156]: get_ys2(np.arange(5)[None,:])
Out[156]: 
array([[-2.        , -1.89473684, -1.78947368, -1.68421053, -1.57894737,
        -1.47368421, -1.36842105, -1.26315789, -1.15789474, -1.05263158,
        -0.94736842, -0.84210526, -0.73684211, -0.63157895, -0.52631579,
        -0.42105263, -0.31578947, -0.21052632, -0.10526316,  0.        ]])
```

With your test case:

```
In [146]: n = 1000
     ...: xs = np.random.random((n,5))
     ...: ys = np.apply_along_axis(get_ys, 1, xs)
In [147]: ys.shape
Out[147]: (1000, 20)
```

Two timings:

```
In [148]: timeit ys = np.apply_along_axis(get_ys, 1, xs)
     ...: 
106 ms ± 303 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [149]: timeit ys = np.apply_along_axis(get_ys1, 1, xs)
     ...: 
88 ms ± 98.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

and testing this

```
In [150]: ys2 = get_ys2(xs)
In [151]: ys2.shape
Out[151]: (1000, 20)
In [152]: np.allclose(ys, ys2)
Out[152]: True
In [153]: timeit ys2 = get_ys2(xs)
424 µs ± 484 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

It matches values, and improves speed a lot.

In the new function, `args` can now be (n,5).  And if `x` is (20,1), the result is (20,n), which I transpose on the return.

Comment: This is very very impressive, thank you very much! I'm still trying to understand everything you did in the answer with the broadcasting, the transpose and the creation of new axis